# How to check response code use rest-client Resource

Tags: ruby, rspec, rest-client

I'm fairly new to Ruby. I'm trying to write a RSpec test against the following class:

```
require 'rest-client'

class Query
  def initialize
    @@log = Logger.new(STDOUT)
    RestClient.log = @@log
    @@user = "joe@example.com"
    @@password = "joe123"
  end

  def get_details
    begin
      url = "http://api.example.com/sample/12345"
      resource = RestClient::Resource.new(url, :user => @@user, 
        :password => @@password, :content_type => :json, :accept => :json)
      details = resource.get
    rescue => e
      throw e # TODO: something more intelligent
    end
  end
end
```

I've discovered that unlike `RestClient.get` which returns a `Response`, `Resource.get` returns the body of the response as a `String`. I'd like to get Response working, because I will want to expand this to make different sub-resource calls.

Is there a way that I can find out the HTTP status code of the GET call response? That would allow me to write a test like:

```
require 'rspec'
require_relative 'query'

describe "Query site" do
  before :all do
    @query = Query.new
  end

  it "should connect to site" do
    details = @query.get_details
    expect(details).to_not be_nil
    expect(details.code).to eq(200)
    expect(details.body).to match /description12345/
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get returns an instance of the class RestClient::Response that inherits from the String class.

You can still check the return code by calling the method code `details.code`. Other methods are for example `details.headers` and `details.cookies`

Comment: That hasn't been my experience. When I examine `details.class`, it returns `String`.

Comment: @neontapir RestClient extends the string it gets from the http-request and extends it with RestClient::Response module. So both `details.is_a?(String)` and `details.is_?(RestClient::Response)`. If you try to run `details.code` it should return the code details in AbstractResponse.

The code for RestClient::Response can be found [here](https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client/blob/master/lib/restclient/response.rb#L17)

Comment: Thank you, I understand what's happening now. Thanks for your patience!